# “file not found” in Bridging Header when importing Objective-C frameworks into Swift project by CocoaPod

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, bridging-header

I got a swift project ,and use CocoaPod to import the third part repositories.  In pod file I use `use_frameworks!`, so the repositories will build into framework to use. And I import the ObjC framework like `#import ""` or `#import <>` in my Bridging Header.
In this situation, I run the project, it works. but When I archive,        “file not found” is found in Bridging Header file.

```
`BridgingHeader.h:5:9: error: 'RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>' file not found 
#import <RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header 'xxx-Bridging-Header'`
```

and

```
`failed to import bridging header '/Users/xxx/Documents/xxxProjectName/xxxProjectName/xxxProjectName-Bridging-Header.h'`
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but when i run XCode bot integration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution is :
Do not import the ObjC framework in bridging header file, just import the framework in the files in which the framework is needed. just like:
`import xxxframework`

Comment: Thanks a ton! Initially error was "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" with BridgingHeader "file not found".

Comment: If I do what you say, I get a "no such module" error on the "import xxxframework" line of my .swift file.

Answer (score 1):

I went to Target->Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries 
added the framework I was trying to import inside the bridging header file.

It fixed the error for me.