# Issues with use_frameworks in Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm currently having an issue with integrating a specific cocoapod and was wondering if I could get some help/insight. I'm trying to integrate the JSQMessages pod, found here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.

When I add the pod to my Podfile and run pod install, I'm not able to import the project like I need to. It doesn't recognize it. I found out that this is because I need the use_frameworks! line in my Podfile. However, when I add that line, my project breaks because I use Google Maps and Braintree APIs through cocoapods as well, and those break with the use_frameworks line. I've encountered this problem in the past with other pods, but was able to fix them with manual import. This one doesn't seem as straightforward. I have a couple questions

- Looking at the pod, is it possible to do a manual import for JSQMessages pod?
- Is there a way also to use_frameworks for some pods and not for others, because that could solve it as well?

Any other solutions to my issue would be a big help as well! Please let me know as soon as possible!

Comment: I met your problem too, If you use `use_frameworks!`, that you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677

Comment: The answer for the second question is that using use_frameworks is a choice of yes or no, you can't use it partly.

Comment: I guess my end goal is not to use use_frameworks!. When I try to manually import without using that line, the pod is not recognized

Comment: Some repository is only support framework, if you want to use it, you definitely have to build it into framework.

Answer (score 0):

I added both the

```
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'Braintree'
```

to my won project that has  `pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'` installed and it build fine. So this is what I think your problem may be.

The root of your issue is not with the `use_frameworks!` line in your `podfile`
The problem is that you are using your `PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj` but with pods when you run the `pod install` command this creates a new `PROJECTNAME.xcworkspace`

Close your Project and open the new PROJECTNAME.workspace that was created after you run pod install in your projects root directory in terminal.

Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: No, I have been using .xcworkspace this entire time. Do you think it would be beneficial to recreate my workspace with pod install, using the use_frameworks! line.