# Integrating Microsoft Cognitive SpeechSDK framework into a Swift app

Tags: swift, frameworks, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, bridging-header

I'm trying to integrate Microsoft [Bing Speech API](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS) with `SpeechRecognitionService` into my Swift application. Unfortunately, the Microsoft SDK only supports Objective-C atm, so I get around by adding `#import "SpeechRecognitionService.h"` to the Bridging Header after importing the `SpeechSDK.framework`, but I got the `file not found` error.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I did try `import SpeechSDK` framework directly into the needed class before but it was not working.

In my case, I'm still using the Bridging Header in order to import the framework. `#import "SpeechRecognitionService.h"` didn't work but a slight change as below works for me.

```
#import "SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“file not found” in Bridging Header when importing Objective-C frameworks into Swift project by CocoaPod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I'm still using the Bridging Header in order to import the framework. `#import "SpeechRecognitionService.h"` didn't work but a slight change as below works for me.

```
#import "SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add header to bridging header, you can simply import the framework. From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> Importing External Frameworks
>
> You can import external frameworks that have a pure Objective-C
>   codebase, a pure Swift codebase, or a mixed-language codebase. The
>   process for importing an external framework is the same whether the
>   framework is written in a single language or contains files from both
>   languages. When you import an external framework, make sure the
>   Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set
>   to “Yes”.
>
> You can import a framework into any Swift file within a different
>   target using the following syntax:
>
> import FrameworkName

See also [“file not found” in Bridging Header when importing Objective-C frameworks into Swift project by CocoaPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s?rq=1)